# Postgresql repmgr warning does not disappear

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-22.04, postgresql-14, postgresql-15, postgresql-16

I've upgraded the ubuntu from 20 to 22 but now i have a problem with my repmgr

```
postgres@prod-sql-01:~$ repmgr cluster show
WARNING:  database "repmgr" has a collation version mismatch
DETAIL:  The database was created using collation version 2.31, but the operating system provides version 2.35.
HINT:  Rebuild all objects in this database that use the default collation and run ALTER DATABASE repmgr REFRESH COLLATION VERSION, or build PostgreSQL with the right library version.
 ID | Name  | Role    | Status    | Upstream | Location | Priority | Timeline | Connection string
----+-------+---------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------------------------------------------
 1  | node1 | primary | * running |          | default  | 100      | 1        | host=x.x.x.x user=repmgr dbname=repmgr
 2  | node2 | standby |   running | node1    | default  | 50       | 1        | host=y.y.y.y user=repmgr dbname=repmgr
 3  | node3 | witness | * running | node1    | default  | 0        | n/a      | host=z.z.z.z user=repmgr dbname=repmgr
```

I've made the following command to fix it but the error persists:

```
psql

postgres=# \c repmgr

WARNING:  database "repmgr" has a collation version mismatch
DETAIL:  The database was created using collation version 2.31, but the operating system provides version 2.35.
HINT:  Rebuild all objects in this database that use the default collation and run ALTER DATABASE repmgr REFRESH COLLATION VERSION, or build PostgreSQL with the right library version.
You are now connected to database "repmgr" as user "postgres".

repmgr=# REINDEX DATABASE repmgr; ALTER DATABASE repmgr REFRESH COLLATION VERSION;

REINDEX
NOTICE:  changing version from 2.31 to 2.35
ALTER DATABASE
```

The log shows the version was updated but the warning keeps appearing.

What can i do or what im doing wrong?

I made the recommended as showed above and i expect to have a cluster without warnings

Comment: Problem Fixed:
If someone passes for the same the solution is do the same commands against the witness node...
I thought we only need to to this on the primary but aparently the witness needs it too. Thank you wall

Comment: make your own answer with extended explanation

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that

```
REINDEX DATABASE repmgr; ALTER DATABASE repmgr REFRESH COLLATION VERSION;
```

was only executed for the `primary` node, but not the other nodes:

```
 ID | Name  | Role    | Status    | Upstream | Location | Priority | Timeline | Connection string
----+-------+---------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------------------------------------------
 1  | node1 | primary | * running |          | default  | 100      | 1        | host=x.x.x.x user=repmgr dbname=repmgr
 2  | node2 | standby |   running | node1    | default  | 50       | 1        | host=y.y.y.y user=repmgr dbname=repmgr
 3  | node3 | witness | * running | node1    | default  | 0        | n/a      | host=z.z.z.z user=repmgr dbname=repmgr
```